# Displaying multiple users as they join with Socket IO

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to create a list of people who join a 'party room' in Socket IO. Once all players are accounted for, the host will lock the party room and views will be served to users. However, this is failing so far.

The console log is reading that the data is there, playerName is defined but I'm still getting an error. This currently works with just one playerWaiting, however, new players override the div instead of listing out. If anyone could point out the correct way to do this, that would be great.

> Object {gameId: 76223, playerName: "cate", mySocketId: "zja-AP-wZ45JLqPg-c7c"} app.js:373
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'playerName' of undefined app.js:373
>
> App.Host.updateWaitingScreenapp.js:77
>
> IO.playerJoinedRoomsocket.io.js:633
>
> EventEmitter.emitsocket.io.js:2248
>
> SocketNamespace.onPacketsocket.io.js:1930
>
> Socket.onPacketsocket.io.js:1332
>
> Transport.onPacketsocket.io.js:1303
>
> Transport.onDatasocket.io.js:2378
>
> websocket.onmessage

HTML

```
<script id="create-game-template" type="text/template">
    <div class="createGameWrapper">
        <div class="info">
            <div id="betSummary"></div>
            <div class="copy">Share the URL and Game ID below to let your mates have a punt on the action.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="gameURL" class="infoBig">Error!</div>

        <div class="info">Then click <strong>JOIN</strong> and <br/> enter the following Game ID:</div>
        <div id="spanNewGameCode" class="gameId">Error!</div>

        <button id="btnLockGame" class="btn">LOCK GAME</button>
        <div id="playersWaiting1"></div>
        <div id="playersWaiting2"></div>
        <div id="playersWaiting3"></div>
        <div id="playersWaiting4"></div>
        <div id="playersWaiting5"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS

```
updateWaitingScreen: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            // Store the new player's data on the Host.
            App.Host.players.push(data);

            // Increment the number of players in the room
            App.Host.numPlayersInRoom += 1;

            // Update host screen
            $('#playersWaiting1')
                .append('<p/>')
                .text('Player ' + App.Host.players[0].playerName + ' joined the game.');
            $('#playersWaiting2')
                .append('<p/>')
                .text('Player ' + App.Host.players[1].playerName + ' joined the game.');
            $('#playersWaiting3')
                .append('<p/>')
                .text('Player ' + App.Host.players[2].playerName + ' joined the game.');                    
            $('#playersWaiting4')
                .append('<p/>')
                .text('Player ' + App.Host.players[3].playerName + ' joined the game.');
            $('#playersWaiting5')
                .append('<p/>')
                .text('Player ' + App.Host.players[4].playerName + ' joined the game.');


            $( "#btnLockGame" ).click(function() {
                IO.socket.emit('hostRoomFull',App.gameId);
            });
    },
```

Server side

```
function playerJoinGame(data) {
//console.log('Player ' + data.playerName + 'attempting to join game: ' + data.gameId );

// A reference to the player's Socket.IO socket object
var sock = this;

// Look up the room ID in the Socket.IO manager object.
var room = gameSocket.manager.rooms["/" + data.gameId];

// If the room exists...
if( room != undefined ){
    // attach the socket id to the data object.
    data.mySocketId = sock.id;

    // Join the room
    sock.join(data.gameId);

    //console.log('Player ' + data.playerName + ' joining game: ' + data.gameId );

    // Emit an event notifying the clients that the player has joined the room.
    io.sockets.in(data.gameId).emit('playerJoinedRoom', data);

} else {
    // Otherwise, send an error message back to the player.
    this.emit('error',{message: "This room does not exist."} );
    }
}
```

Comment: where's your server code ?

Comment: Apologies, previously omitted it as I had debugged my way back to $('#playersWaiting1'). I've updated the post with the server code.

Comment: Where are you trying to access `playerName` ? `object.playerName` ? your object is undefined.

Comment: This line `App.Host.players[0].playerName` should return the playerName which is stored as `data.playerName`

Comment: try to `console.log (App.Host.players)` to see its contents.

Comment: It's coming back undefined so that's the issue. Is this the best way to be wait for all players to join then store their names in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what line is failing. What is app.js:373?

My guess is that you're trying to read all values in the array before it is full. If there is no element  3, trying to get the `playerName` from undefined will throw an error.

Either run a loop from 0 to the number of players in the room (which assumes your count is correct and maintained)

or,

Check if `App.Host.players[#]` is defined. If not defined, output `.text('seat # waiting')`, otherwise check for the `playerName`. This can be a loop or hard-coded like you have.